# Installing Python with homebrew on Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, mac, python, osx-mountain-lion, homebrew

I was trying to follow [this](http://www.thisisthegreenroom.com/2011/installing-python-numpy-scipy-matplotlib-and-ipython-on-lion/) tutorial and I got stuck. After issuing the command

```
brew install python --framework --universal
```

I get

```
 ==> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/bin/python -s setup.py --no-user-cfg install

File "/private/tmp/__UNKNOWN__-zSD0/distribute-0.6.28/distribute_setup.py",
 line 347, in _patch_egg_dir_rename_path(path)  

File "/private/tmp/__UNKNOWN__-zSD0/distribute-0.6.28/distribute_setup.py",
 line 259, in _rename_path

 os.rename(path, new_name) OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

READ THIS: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting

These open issues may also help:
     https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/12918
```

for output.

I have looked around (including at the provided links) and I found some suggestions about removing the system's python framework, which I have, and I am now python-less and still can't get the command to work. I am not a unix/mac-os expert, so any idea would be welcome...

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems myself installing python.

First you should check that your PATH variable looks like this: (something like this DO NOT COPY PASTE)

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

EDIT: You can change the path variable by running the following command:

```
export PATH=/here/goes/the:/rearranged/list
```

Or by creating a file named ".bash_profile" in your home directory and put it there, so it will only affect your account. Here's an example of my .bash_profile:

```
$ cat .bash_profile 
export PATH='/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin'
```

"/usr/local/bin" should be first of all, such that your installation of python is prefered over the (outdated) system installation.

After that I did

```
$ brew update
$ brew install python
```

Otherwise try to run:

```
$ brew doctor
```

and follow the instruction or clues given...